# What is a hyphen beside a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I saw in some of our scripts  that there  is a hyphen attached to a shell variable. For example:

```
if [ -z ${X-} ]
```

What does this hyphen symbol beside the variable do here.
I cannot find any documentation online for this.

Comment: It's all explained in the [_Shell Parameter Expansion_ section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all explained in the [*Shell Parameter Expansion* section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

Just before this there is:

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

So:

```
${X-stuff}
```

expands to:

- The expansion of `$X` if `X` is set
- `stuff` if `X` is unset.

Try it:

```
$ unset X
$ echo "${X-stuff}"
stuff
$ X=
$ echo "${X-stuff}"

$ X=hello
$ echo "${X-stuff}"
hello
$
```

Now your expansion is

```
${X-}
```

so you guess that it expands to the expansion of `$X` if `X` is set, and to the null string if `X` is unset.

---

Why would you want to do this? to me it seems that this is a workaround the `set -u`:

```
$ set -u
$ unset X
$ echo "$X"
bash: X: unbound variable
$ echo "${X-}"

$
```

---

Finally, your test

```
if [ -z "${X-}" ]
```

(note the quotes, they are mandatory) tests whether `X` is nil (regardless of `X` being set or not, even if `set -u` is used).

Comment: Please explain what the `-z` means

Comment: @ArielGabizon, see `help test`: _`-z STRING`      True if string is empty._