# what does ${var-value} do in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I was looking at some startup scripts. particularly nginx. I noticed they have a block that looks like this

```
nginx=${NGINX-/usr/sbin/nginx}
prog=`/bin/basename $nginx`
conffile=${CONFFILE-/etc/nginx/nginx.conf}
lockfile=${LOCKFILE-/var/lock/subsys/nginx}
pidfile=${PIDFILE-/var/run/nginx.pid}
SLEEPMSEC=${SLEEPMSEC-200000}
```

I was trying to figure out what the '-' does in the middle of some of the `$` lines

As an experiment I wrote my own script

```
#NGINX="b"


f=${NGINX-/etc/nginx/nginx.conf}
echo $f
```

If I keep the `NGINX` line commented it prints `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but if I uncomment it just prints `b`

So my question is what is the '-' doing and why would you want to use it this way?

Comment: Similarly, [What is a hyphen beside a shell variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964357/what-is-a-hyphen-beside-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Actually, I'm calling [Usage of colon dash in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390406/usage-of-colon-dash-in-bash) a proper duplicate -- the question only covers the `${var:-value}` case, but the answer covers the `${var-value}` case as well.

Comment: BTW, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is one of the better reference sources on parameter expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks those were helpful as well as the wiki page you linked.